# Matlab: Estimating power spectral density of an experimental data?

Tags: matlab, fft, power-spectral-density, window-functions

How do I estimate PSD in matlab ? There are lots of methods to estimate, depending on application.

I am using an experimental data to identify faults ( e.g. interturn fault of electric motor), which gives periodic/regular waveforms (pre-fault) but erratically different (or could have some periodicity) waveforms (post-fault).
In this application, my voltage signal, v(t) is sampled and collected using DAQ systems.

Questions:

1. Can v(t) be considered a wide-sense-stationary random process (WSS-RP) ?

I understand that there are multiple ways to get PSD. 
 What is the best suggestion ? Is it ...

1. By fourier transform the autocorrelation, if only v(t) is WSS-RP. [as described by Wiener-Khintichine Theorem]
2. By

   - splitting the signal,v(t) into multiple frames( or segments)
   - applying window function : multiply each segment by a hamming window (i.e. convolution in freq. domain )
   - FFT each of the windowed signal
   - either multiply its conjugate or absolute square, to get the spectral density of the segment
   - resulting spectra are averaged to get the ultimate averaged spectrum
     Just like the explanation here [Fig 9.1](http://www.dspguide.com/ch9/1.htm), [Sect.11: Averaging Periodograms, pg14](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa719/snoa719.pdf)

What is the difference in the mathworks' application note in (www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrum.html)

Can someone please guide in the codings ?

Feel grateful in the midst of dsp gurus !
kit

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB has built-in functions taking care of the steps you mention in 2. You can check out the **pwelch** function ([here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html)) which uses Welch's method for PSD estimation.([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method)) 
The choice of segment length, number, overlap and windowing function presents a trade-off between bias and variance.